# how to toggle particular div element in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have list of product , If I click on one product it needs to be added in database and again if I click on same product it should be removed from database, I am toggling `wishlistFlag` on `ng-click`. It should be fine on one div element, for second div element it is working reverse of first div element, I mean in case first product is added then if I click second product it has to be added but it is removing first product.

```
 <div class="hmpal-prprt-post-wdgt hmpal-prprt-wishlist">
    <a href="">
        <span class="prprt-icon"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" 
            ng-click="WishlistAdd($index,project.propertyId)"></i></span>
        <span>Wishlist</span>
    </a>
 </div>
```

And inside Controller code is here,

```
a.WishlistAdd = function (index,propertyId) {

    a.wishlistFlag = !a.wishlistFlag;

    var data = {
        wishlistFlag:a.wishlistFlag,
        propertyId:propertyId
    };

    e.createWishLists(data).then(function (result) {
        alert("sucesss");
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function (error) {
       alert("error");
       alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

How I can implement toggle `wishlistFlag` for different product .

Comment: You need to maintain separate flags for each product. Here you are maintaining only one flag for all products.

Comment: how to make separate flags for each product. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want at most one product selected in your wish list, instead of having a `boolean` flag, you can use the selected product id (called `propertyId` in your code if I'm right). The `selectedProductId` variable, defined in the controller, is either `null` if there is no product selected, or the product id if there is one.

The *toggling* is done by checking if the current selected id is equal to the clicked one.

I assume that

1. when `wishListFlag === true` in the sent data, you want to add the
   product identified by `propertyId`, and otherwise, remove the
   product from the database.
2. when you add a product, the server side
   actually replace the selected product if there is an existing one.

---

```
// Is there a selected product ?
var selectedProductId = null;

a.WishlistAdd = function (index, propertyId) {

    selectedProductId = (selectedProductId === propertyId ? null : propertyId);

    var data = {
        wishlistFlag: (selectedProductId !== null),
        propertyId: propertyId
    };

    e.createWishLists(data).then(function (result) {
        alert("sucesss");
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function (error) {
       alert("error");
       alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of $index to have seperate flag to each of the wishList. Here, you can write your code as..

`a.wishListFlag[index]`

Answer (score 0):

maintain a array of added propertyIds before save to the database check that id is in array if so remove from database and array else remove from database and array.

```
    var wishList = [];

    a.WishlistAdd = function (index,propertyId) {


        var data = {
            wishlistFlag: wishList.indexOf(propertyId) === -1,
            propertyId:propertyId
        };

        e.createWishLists(data).then(function (result) {

            //add or remove propertyid from whishList
            if(data.wishlistFlag)
                wishList.push(propertyId);

            else
                wishList.splice(wishList.indexOf(propertyId), 1);

            alert("sucesss");
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }, function (error) {
           alert("error");
           alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
```